# how to retrieve content from database when it was changed in jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp, jquery

i'm beginner of html5&jsp,
I just want to make roomlist retrieve when it have changed from database.
Basically when i click roomlist which is on the header from my main page i can get roomlist but if another user make room, i can't get roomlist in real time. please help me and Thanks

hear is my mainpage code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("euc-kr"); %>
<html>
<Head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
    <title>RoomListing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ReloadPage() {
       location.reload();
        alert("hihi");
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi");    

        setInterval("ReLoadPage()", 3000);
    });
    </script>   
</Head>
<body>
<section id="page1" data-role="page">
<%
//String subject = request.getParameter("subject");


Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/test",
             "root", "1234" );
    if(conn==null)
        throw new Exception("데이터베이스에 연결할 수 없습니다.<br>");


    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from roominfo");
    ArrayList<String> room_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(rs.next()){
        room_list.add(rs.getString("id")+":"+rs.getString("subject")+":"+rs.getString("content"));
    }


    int num = room_list.size();
    request.setAttribute("num", num);

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){

        String room_name = null;
        String max = room_list.get(i);
        out.print("<input type ='button' id = 'button1' value = "+max+">");
        request.setAttribute("room_name"+i, room_list.get(i));
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}finally{
    try{
        stmt.close();
    }catch (Exception ignored){
    }
    try {
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception ignored){}

    }
//RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("RoomListing1.jsp");
//dispatcher.forward(request, response);

%>  

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a refresh or reload will only change the jsp related stuff like color, image , style etc.
Java code written inside scriptlets got nothing to do with refresh. So when a roomlist is clicked all that is happening is page is refreshed nothing else. If u want to get data dynamically you need to create a servlet to manage the java related activities which should be invoked each time when the user list is clicked or page is refreshed. You cannot write entire code in JSP and its not a good way.

Comment: Thanks, i just solve the problem... actually i put the javascritp reload method in the buttom of this code...and it work. but if i want to upload the page only when the database have changed, should i have to use ajax?? Thanks again